# Ghost Connection with Socket.io, Node.js and Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express, socket.io

**This issue is only happening on Heroku. When testing locally this is not an issue.**

Test URL: https://couchos.herokuapp.com/

When you enter the page the app will prompt you to use your phone and visit the URL provided.

**The problem is that if you do NOTHING after a couple of seconds/minutes (2min max.) the app receives a connection from the control.**

I have the app socket ID in a variable that I pass thru the URL for the control to read it (ex. https://couchos.herokuapp.com/mobile/?**tvSocketId=QrVITPJhYEPxXtvNAAAC**), from there every time the control sends a command, it send it with the socket ID of the app, the server take that socket ID that is received from the control to send a direct message to the app.

I have the code to log in the browser dev console the socket IDs, as well to tell me if the control connection is mobile or tablet (the ghost connection is always mobile).

Can you take a look and please tell me what I may be doing wrong?

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port: ', port);
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var theControl = io.of('/the-control');
var theTV = io.of('/the-tv');

//Routing
app.use('/img',  express.static(__dirname + '/img'));
app.use('/js',  express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));


theControl.on('connection', function (socket) {
//    console.log('The Control Connected, SocketID: ' + socket.id);

    socket.emit('CHECK CONTROL', socket.id);
    socket.on('CONTROL ONLINE', function (data) {
        theTV.to(data.tvSocketId).emit('CONTROL ONLINE', {data: data, controlSocketId: socket.id});
    });

    socket.on('command', function (data) {
        theTV.to(data.socketId).emit('VOLUME UP');
    });
});

theTV.on('connection', function (socket) {
//    console.log('The TV Connected, SocketID: ' + socket.id);

    socket.emit('CHECK TV', socket.id);
});
```

**index.js**

```
socket.on('CONTROL ONLINE', function (data) {
    console.log('THE CONTROL CONNECTED! ', data);
});
socket.on('CHECK TV', function (data) {
    console.log('MY SOCKET-ID: ' + data);
    tvSocketId = data;
});
```

**mobile.js**

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

tvSocketId = getUrlVars()["tvSocketId"];
if (device.mobile() || device.tablet()) {
    socket.emit('CONTROL ONLINE', {tvSocketId:tvSocketId, isMobile: device.mobile(), isTablet: device.tablet()});
}
socket.on('CHECK CONTROL', function(data) {
    console.log('MY SOCKET-ID: ', data);
});

socket.emit('command', {command: 'SINGLE TAP', socketId: tvSocketId});
```